# Arguments for batch size not being captured. Any idea?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I do have following script to capture the command line arguments. Third option for batch size is not being set any idea ? 
**FYI : Only input & ouput file options are required parameter. Batch is optional.**

```
import sys, getopt
import os
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:b",["ifile=","ofile=","bsize="])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print 'file.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile> -b<batchsize>[default=20000000]'
    sys.exit(2)
for opt, arg in opts:
    print opt
    if opt == '-h':
        print 'file.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile> -b<batchsize>[default=20000000]'
        sys.exit()
    elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
        inputFile = arg
    elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
        outputFile = arg
    elif opt in ("-b", "--bsize"):
        print "Another option %s" % opt
        batchsize = arg
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `getopt` instead of `argparse`? The main reason `getopt` exists is for people who already know it (or its C counterpart) so well that they don't want to learn anything new. If that isn't you, why use it?

Comment: Also, it really helps to write code that we can actually run. Your code raises an `IndentationError`, then raises a `NameError` on `argv` if you fix that, etc. … and you're passing `argv` instead of `argv[1:]`, so you end up with everything as an argument and nothing as an option.

Comment: If you fix all of that, contrary to what you claim, the `--bsize` parameter actually _does_ work just fine. It's only the `-b` short version that doesn't (for the reason given in dkamins's answer). That's why it's worth giving actual sample input (a command line you typed) and what the expected and actual output are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems with this script including indent errors and failing to initialize settings first... But let's assume you just copy/pasted it incorrectly.

The answer is that you are missing a ":" after the "b" in your getopt arguments.

This line:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:b",["ifile=","ofile=","bsize="])
```

Should actually be:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:b:",["ifile=","ofile=","bsize="])
```

Comment: thank you very much. I was missing ':'. Yes it was copy paste error. But the scripts and initialization are all done before this part of the code. Thank you again. Will accept this answer in few.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind, I would recommend [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse). It is better usably and not as clunky as getopts.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", "--ifile", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-o", "--ofile", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-b", "--bsize", type=int, default=20000000)
parser.parse_args()
input_file = parser.input
```

etc.

Comment: That's a good suggestion in general, but… the arguments you're parsing are vastly different from the OP's.

Comment: Good suggestion. Will try to change it later.

Comment: @abarnert: Yap, changed to fit more to OP's.